# .proto functions are not defined

Tags: visual-studio, go, protocol-buffers, grpc-go

I'm currently a beginner in learning Go Lang, GRPC, and use of Protobuf. So I am following this video that on how to create a simple API where it sends back a message. Currently I am trying to create a .proto file and  the "package", "option", "service" are undefined and not highlighted as they should be. This is the code inside my .proto file

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3"

package main;

option go_package = "./proto";

service TestApi {
    rpc Echo (ResponseRequest) returns (ResponseRequest) {}
    rpc GetUser (UserRequest) returns (UserResponse) {}
}

message ResponseRequest {
    string msg = 1;
}

message UserRequest {
    string uuid =1;
}

message UserResponse{
    string name = 1;
    int32 age =2;
    string email = 3;
}
```

[image: 1]

I've installed packages for protobuf, grpc and go lang already, but I might be overlooking something.
These are the the things I installed so far in cmd:

```bash
$ go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@v1.28
$ go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@v1.2
```

These are the plugins in VSC Code I used for this specific practice material as well. Not sure if these have conflicts as well.

[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]

This is my first time asking in overflow, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The semicolon at the end of the first line is missing.

Comment: I seem to overlooked that, but with the semicolon added the said function are still highlighted red

Comment: Conventionally, the file would have the extension `.proto` (i.e. `test.proto`) rather than `test_proto`. What is the file type that Visual Code has detected for the file? Look in the bottom right hand corner of the app. Does it say "Protocol Buffers"?

Comment: @DazWilkin it should detect it regardless. The main issue was the .proto buff was not recognized and I couldn't figure it out. I have solved it but I attempted numerous fixes at the same time and then it worked.

Comment: continuing @DazWilkin These are the "fixes" I did to make the protocol buffers be recognized. I used plugins as well:

from scratch I reinstalled packages/libraries needed for protobuf and grpc

Reinstalled plugins in VS Code (Protobuf Support & Proto 3)
2.a: For Proto3 plugin I modified the setting.jso which is nested in "proto":